# XPATH condition to map fields in datamapper

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, datamapper

I need to pass a value to datamapper and retrieve it to map fields. In the below InputXML, 'pages' element is repeated as shown. My output should have only that book object with pages element matched from input. (i.e; I am passing 100 as value for pages through myVariable. Hence output should have only the book element containing 100 pages).

```
<set-session-variable variableName="myVariable" value="100" />
<data-mapper:transform doc:name="XML To XML" config-ref="xml_to_xml" >
        <data-mapper:input-arguments>
            <data-mapper:input-argument key="myVariable">#[sessionVars.myVariable]</data-mapper:input-argument>
        </data-mapper:input-arguments>
    </data-mapper:transform>
```

InputXML:

```
<catalogue>
<books>
 <book>
   <name>book1</name>
   <author>author1</author>
   <pages>100</pages>
 </book>
 <book>
   <name>book2</name>
   <author>author2</author>
   <pages>200</pages>
 </book>
 <book>
   <name>book3</name>
   <author>author3</author>
   <pages>300</pages>
 </book>
</books>
<writeups>
 <a>1</a>
</writeups>
<catalogue>
```

OutputXML:

```
<catalogue2>
<books>
 <book>
   <name>book1</name>
   <author>author1</author>
   <pages>100</pages>
 </book>

<writeups>
 <a>1</a>
</writeups>
<catalogue2>
```

Approach1:

```
//Catalogue/books[inputArguments.myVariable=Catalogues/books/book/pages]/book/pages
```

In the xpath rule for pages, I am trying to pick such a  book object which has value of pages as the input argument passed. But this approach throws an exception saying

```
org.jetel.exception.JetelRuntimeException: net.sf.saxon.trans.StaticError: Undeclared      variable in a standalone expression
```

Could you please correct the xpath expression?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use input arguments directly into an XPath expression. Maybe you should first use the input argument to add it to the payload (XML) and then do a second datamapper and in this second transformation use this added field:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/Using+Input+Arguments

Comment: @Anton Kupias could you help us with this ?